# Backbonejs collection returns wrong data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, tastypie

I'm using Tastypie for my RESTful api and Backbonejs for front end. the `fetch` with models works fine, however, with `Backbone.Collection` I seem to get the wrong response:

```
_byCid: Object
  _byId: Object
  _callbacks: Object
  _onModelEvent: function () { [native code] }
  _removeReference: function () { [native code] }
  length: 1
  models: Array[1]
       0: d
       _callbacks: Object
       _changed: false
       _changing: false
       _escapedAttributes: Object
       _previousAttributes: Object
       attributes: Object
           cid: "c14"
           collection: d
               __proto__: o
               length: 1
               __proto__: Array[0]
               __proto__: o
```

Here is my collection :

```
define(
[
    'models/ad',
],
function(AdModel){
    return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/api/v1/ad',
        model: AdModel,

        initialize: function(){
            this.fetch({
                success: function(coll, resp){
                    console.log(coll);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

);

And here is my Model:

```
   define(
[],
function(){
    return Backbone.Model.extend({

    });
}
```

);

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for... It seems to be creating a collection and populating it with a model. Can you post the raw data `fetch` returns and what you expect it to do?

Comment: It seems to be populating it with array of models, which is not what I should expect from a `Collection`, right? there should be a collection attribute in the returned data, is that correct? How do I copy the raw data from the console btw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what I had to change was my `Collection.parse` method.

```
define(
   [
     'models/ad',
   ],
function(AdModel){
   return Backbone.Collection.extend({
      url: '/api/v1/ad',
      model: AdModel,
      parse: function(data){
          return data.objects;
      },
      initialize: function(){
        this.fetch({
            success: function(coll, resp){
                console.log(coll);
            }
        });
    }
  });
}
```

and everything worked fine.